# apply function on dataframe involving two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with 3 columns and milion rows:

```
    time      longitude      latitude
    1         x1              y1
    2         x2              y2
    3         x3              y3
    ...
```

I want to apply a function to calculate distance based on the longitude and latitude. Basically I need a way to express the function can handle two adjacent rows in dataframe
like

```
    compute_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

I know there are ways to apply function along axis 1 and 0, but they seem only apply to single row or column. How can I express something involving several rows or columns.

Comment: If you just want the difference then just call `diff` to do the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply won't be able to this, but you can do something simple like the following:

```
def compute_distance(df):
    next_df = df.shift(-1)
    return distance_on_unit_sphere(df["lat"], df["long"],
                                   next_df["lat"], next_df["long"]):
```

from here
http://www.johndcook.com/python_longitude_latitude.html